# How do I access the data in JSON converted to hash by crack in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

Here is the example from the crack documentation:

```
json = '{"posts":[{"title":"Foobar"}, {"title":"Another"}]}'
Crack::JSON.parse(json)
=> {"posts"=>[{"title"=>"Foobar"}, {"title"=>"Another"}]}
```

But how do I actually access the data in the hash?

I've tried the following:

```
array = Crack::JSON.parse(json)
array["posts"]
```

array["posts"] shows all the values, but I tried array["posts"]["title"] and it didn't work.

**Here is what I am trying to parse as an example:**

```
{"companies"=>[{"city"=>"San Mateo", "name"=>"Jigsaw", "address"=>"777 Mariners Island Blvd Ste 400", "zip"=>"94404-5059", "country"=>"USA", "companyId"=>4427170, "activeContacts"=>168, "graveyarded"=>false, "state"=>"CA"}], "totalHits"=>1}
```

I want to access the individual elements under companies....like city and name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
hash = {
  "companies" => [
    {
      "city"           => "San Mateo", 
      "name"           => "Jigsaw", 
      "address"        => "777 Mariners Island Blvd Ste 400", 
      "zip"            => "94404-5059", 
      "country"        => "USA", 
      "companyId"      => 4427170, 
      "activeContacts" => 168, 
      "graveyarded"    => false, 
      "state"          => "CA"
    }
  ], 
  "totalHits" => 1
}

hash['companies'].each{ |i| 
  puts "city => #{i['city']}"
  puts "name => #{i['name']}" 
}
# >> city => San Mateo
# >> name => Jigsaw

hash['companies'][0]['city'] # => "San Mateo"
hash['companies'][0]['name'] # => "Jigsaw"
```

The problem is you didn't account for the array that `companies` points to.

Comment: should I take the array and convert it into another hash to make it easier to access?  or convert into an object, or just go about this approach?  it seems to work this way...wanted other ideas...thank you

Comment: Whether to create an object, or leave it as an of hashes is really your call. If you are processing the data as a service for other code, say, as part of a module, then I think creating an object is good, because you can hide functionality if you want. If you are parsing the results for your code only, then keeping it as an array of hashes might be more convenient. That's the first question I always ask myself when I'm writing something non-trivial: Will I be sharing it or not?